# Java - rewrite a List<List<String>>

Tags: java, list, tableview

I want to rewrite my `List<List<String>>` with new values.

Im working with a TableView (JavaFX) and when I reorder the columns, the DataList should get updated/rewritten.

This is how the Table with the data looks like (for example here I want to exchange the first with the secound column):[image]

At this example I want that the 1. column has the data of the scond, and the 2. column has the data of the first...

I wrote this code, but it doesnt work:

```
private ObservableList<List<String>> fnlData;
.
.
tmpListData = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
tmpListData.addAll(fnlData);
int i = 0;
for (List<String> ls : fnlData){
    int j = 0;
    for (String s : ls){
         s = tmpListData.get(i).get(colOrder[j]);
         j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Im getting this error:[image]

When I move for the first time the column,nothing happens but the new column order number is correct.
The second time I reorder the column, this error appears and the column order number is completely false...

*little advice:*

*outer list are the rows, and inner list are the columns*

*fist the columns are in this order = 0,1,2,3,4...*

*then when I reorder the columns, I save the new order in colOrder(//=5,0,1,2,3,4)*

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean? Please include the exact error or problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: also please describe your requirement clearly, you want to interchange first 2 column itself or have to implement same for remaining column also..?

Comment: I updated the question...

Comment: Please stop posting minor variations of what is essentially the same question. If your question is not getting answered to your satisfaction, it is likely that it is because it is not clearly enough stated, or does not provide enough information. Instead, please go back end edit the previous question to provide enough information, preferably in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to get the kind of answer you need.

Comment: James_D this is the main question, because here I described it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does not work? The list is not changed? or is the view not updated?

If i assume that the outer list represent the rows and the inner the column-values and that the `colOrder` is a list of integers containing something like `colOrder[0] = 1` that means the first column (number 0) displays the values from column 1, i would have someting like this:

```
private ObservableList<List<String>> fnlData;

tmpListData = new LinkedList<List<String>>();

for (List<String> row : fnlData){
    List<String> newRow = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int col : colOrder){
        String value = row.get(col);
        newRow.add(value);
    }
    tmpListData.add(newRow);
}
```

**Update according to comment**

s is never used and s is only valid in (!) the for loop, but does not change the value in `ls`.
To change that:

```
...
for (List<String> ls : fnlData){    
    for (int j=0;j<ls.size();j++){
        ls.set(j, tmpListData.get(i).get(colOrder[j]));            
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I updated the quesiton, take a look

Comment: udpated. It's a little bit lavish, but more understandable

Comment: with your code im getting the same error

Comment: At this line `String value = row.get(col);` ?

Comment: to add some thoughts:
obviously the colOrder is larger than your number of columns. This is simply a failure when your are create the colOrder, or it's due to the presentation-mechanism of the table. I don't know the JavaFX table, but some table implementations use somekind of an additional view-model. so, changes (add, deletes etc.) within a table must be commited to be present in the underlying model (which is you fnlData)

Comment: Do someone maybe know why Im getting this :http://i.imgur.com/RPyyl3K.png

Comment: because you don't use the variable s after overwriting it.
This `s = tmpListData.get(i).get(colOrder[j]);` does not change the value within the `ls` list!

Comment: next problem: when I change the value here : ls.set(k,tmpListData.get(i).get(colOrder[k])); 
 is changes also in tmpListData .-.

Comment: Theorefore my proposed solution, where you entirly create a new empty row...

Comment: ok thx, now I fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain you actually want to change your lists? You could wrap your list in another `List` that essentially reorders the elements.

```
class ReorderedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> {

    final List<T> l;
    final int[] order;

    public ReorderedList(List<T> l) {
        this.l = l;
        order = new int[l.size()];
        // Start as original list.
        for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
            order[i] = i;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        // Apply the reorder.
        return l.get(order[index]);
    }

    public void swap(int c1, int c2) {
        int temp = order[c1];
        order[c1] = order[c2];
        order[c2] = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return l.size();
    }

}

public void test() {
    ReorderedList<String> s = new ReorderedList(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three"));
    System.out.println(s);
    s.swap(0, 1);
    System.out.println(s);

}
```